# Logarithmic Distortion in Image OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, distortion

I'm trying to stretch an image gradually in the x axis. How can I do this in OpenCV C++?
The specific problem is: I have an acoustic image where the x axis represents the distance to the objects. In order to use template matching and have only one template to improve the execution time. For this I have to distort the image, upsize along with the distance increase. And for bigger distances, it's the inverse situation, I'll have to downsize the image.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. I'm hoping providing more information ?

For example, could you post the original image a minimal snippet of your attempt so other could attempt to replicate the issue and support ? Do you have an example of the template and the image your trying tying to find the template within ? The upsizing/downsizing part sounds confusing (to me). Using `cv::resize` should help with both upscale/downscale and stretch, though it feels there's more to what you're asking than this.